# Open a custom phone dialer key pad

Tags: android, android-keypad

I want to open a phone dialer key pad in my layout . Like this `[Application][1]`.

[image]

I can open phone default dialer Uri by writing this.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.DIAL");

    /** Starting the Dialer activity */
    startActivity(intent);
```

Any tutorials or link is appreciated.